# Is the SCAD a sort of BLUE estimator in high dimension?

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization

Given a response vector $y$ and a data matrix $X$, the OLS estimator can be obtained by solving the minimization problem:

$$ min_{\beta}\left\{\|y-X\beta \|_2^2\right\}$$

Under the OLS hypothesis, this is known as the best linear unbiased estimator, where *best* refers to being the unbiased estimator with minimum variance. On the other hand, the SCAD-penalized estimator comes from solving

$$ min_{\beta}\left\{|y-X\beta \|_2^2+p(\beta)\right\}$$

where the derivative of the penalty function is

$$p^{\prime}(\beta)=\lambda\left[I(\beta \leq \lambda)+\frac{(a \lambda-\beta)_{+}}{(a-1) \lambda} I(\beta>\lambda)\right]$$

SCAD penality is aimed for high dimensional scenarios, and as stated in the original [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3085904.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A897f119bca383d427b4236a2b8b5ca3a), **provides sparse, unbiased solutions.** Even more, SCAD is an oracle estimator, and as stated again in the paper, this means that the estimator
can correctly select the nonzero coefficients with probability converging to
one, and that the estimators of the nonzero coefficients are asymptotically normal **with the same means and covariances that they would have if the
zero coefficients were known in advance.**

So my question is, is the SCAD a sort of BLUE estimator in high dimensional scenarios? I know that these are asymptotical properties but still, it seems to good to be true, especially when comparing it with other estimators like LASSO, which is biased.